# How to convert a Matrix to a DistMatrix in Elemental?

Tags: linear-algebra, parallel-computing, grid

I have a `Matrix<double>` on a single core, the result of doing an `MPI_Reduce`. I want to do the Cholesky, so I need to distribute over multiple cores.  What's the easiest/most standard way of doing this in Elemental?  Do I need to `MPI_Bcast` it out to all nodes first, and then move it into a `DistMatrix`, or is there some way of doing something like:

```
Matrix<double> A = doSomeStuff();
DistMatrix<double, single-node> AdistSingle( A );
DistMatrix<double> Adist(AdistSingle );
```

or perhaps:

```
Matrix<double> A = doSomeStuff();
DistMatrix<double> Adist(A );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DistMatrix<T,CIRC,CIRC>` was recently created for exactly this situation and stores a fully copy of the matrix on a single process. If you have an $n \times n$ `Matrix<double>` stored on the root process, you can distribute it as follows:

```
// Construct an n x n matrix owned by process 0
DistMatrix<double,CIRC,CIRC> ARoot( n, n );
// Have the root process fill the local matrix of ARoot
if( commRank == 0 )
    ARoot.Matrix() = A;
// Redistribute ARoot into the standard matrix distribution
// (via a scatter)
DistMatrix<double> ADist( ARoot );
```

Note that the `DistMatrix<T,CIRC,CIRC>` class is very new and that the syntax might be simplified in the near future.

Comment: It might be worth allowing `DistMatrix<T,CIRC,CIRC>` to accept a `Matrix<T>` as input, and having the former attach to the latter, so that the extra `(n,n)` allocation does not take place here.

Comment: Agreed, this is planned and only should only take a handful of lines of code, but, as I warned, the distribution is very new.